# Connecting to AWS MQTT with .NET

Tags: .net, uwp, aws-iot

I have a .Net/UWP application that I need to modify to send status via MQTT on AWS. I see plenty of examples in how to publish/subscribe using other languages, but for .Net the information that I've found seems to be outdated and no longer applicable.

In the .Net AWSSDK is there anything that is the equivalent of the `AWSIotClient` class (from Java)? Is there some way to communicate with AWS from .Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had this same problem and never did find an official AWS published C# SDK for Iot Core, though you can communicate with AWS Iot Core using [MQTTnet](https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet).

Here is a snippet on how to connect:

```
var pfxCert = new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(pemCert,pemPrivKey).Export(X509ContentType.Pfx));
var factory = new MqttFactory();
var mqttClient = factory.CreateMqttClient();
var options = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
        .WithTcpServer(endpoint, 8883)
        .WithClientId(clientId)
        .WithCleanSession()
        .WithCommunicationTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
        .WithTls(new MqttClientOptionsBuilderTlsParameters
        {
            UseTls = true,
            SslProtocol = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12,
            IgnoreCertificateRevocationErrors = true,
            IgnoreCertificateChainErrors = true,
            AllowUntrustedCertificates = true,
            Certificates = new List<X509Certificate>
            {
                pfxCert
            }
        })
        .Build();

await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(options, CancellationToken.None);
```

To send a message:

```
var message = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
            .WithTopic(topic)
            .WithPayload(jsonMessage)
            .Build();

var result = await _mqttClient.PublishAsync(message, CancellationToken.None);
```

Comment: Marking this as an answer. It doesn't work in UWP. But it gives me something to work with. 

The UWP version of MQTT doesn't have some of the methods that I need to use this code. I might be able to translate it later. But this gives me a working start. 

Thanks.

Comment: This is not secure as you are ignoring certificate errors.